# PHP how to sanitize an url to a redirection

Tags: php, url

I there

I am creating a login screen and it has the feature to return to a specific page.  For example, let's say that I am working on

> /invoice/insert.php?id=20

if the session expires, then the system redirects to

> login.php?backUrl=**/invoice/insert.php?id=20**

where backUrl is the URL to redirect when the user starts a new session.

Right now, I am cleaning backUrl if:

1. if it contains the word http: or https: then, the whole URL is discarded.
2. if it contains the word .. then it's also discarded.

The authentication is done by each page, so I don't need to secure if somebody tries to bypass the security

> login.php?backUrl=**/adminpanel/users.php**

Am I missing something additional?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use this regex : `^(?!http|\.\.).+` to determine if string are NOT starting by : 'http' or '..'

But is not safe, i recommand you to catch any url who looks like : `^\/\w+`

Example : `/something`

this following code do the trick :

```
function isSafeParam($url) {
    return (bool) preg_match('#^\/\w+#',$url);
}

foreach(["/adminpanel/users.php","http://google.com","../miss/","./dl","//google.com","/my-page"] as $url) {
    var_dump(isSafeParam($url));
}
```

[Online sample](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5f9d0bd2c33ae17aa40f378ba9ce53677f6e5801)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would solve this problem.

1. Have a whitelist of domains that are acceptable. (might just be one)
2. Use a proper url resolver to expand relative redirect urls to their absolute ones
3. Parse the resulting url, and see if the domain is in your whitelist.

Or: find a url parser that can simply tell you whether a url is relative or not.

Using a library that understands URLs is better than doing your own ad-hoc hacking.

Comment: I'm not fancy to add libraries for a small job, after all, every library requires maintenance.   However, I'm clueless how StackOverflow works and why the downvote.

Comment: I generally don't disagree with this. But for things that are sensitive to security there's often a higher likelihood that the author understood all the attack vectors than a simple regex can. Plus I feel it's better to manipulate URLs using their semantic meaning vs doing string manipulation. YMMV.